# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Installing IonCube or Zend Loader

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, hosting, ioncube, zend-loader

I have been trying to get one of these two loaders installed all evening without success. I have narrowed it down to creating a config file. I have put a .config file in a .ebextensions folder located in my root directory of my project, I'm not sure if it needs to be at the same level as my project. But in any case every time 403 error with the following message:

"You don't have permission to access / on this server." If I remove the script the message goes away. I will also include a screenshot of where I can get to with out the .config file included and the reason why I need one of the loaders installed. Thanks in advance here is what my .config file looks like:

```
# Install ioncube
mkdir ion
cd ion
wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86.tar.gz
tar xzvf ioncube_loaders_lin_x86.tar.gz
mv ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so /usr/lib/php/modules/ioncube_loader.so
touch /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini
echo "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/ioncube_loader.so" >> /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini
cd ..
rm -rf ion/
```

Which I got from here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=446182&#446182

[image: Where I can get to without .config file]

Comment: I'm still trying to sort this out myself with little success. Bump

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This installation for IonCube worked just now for EC2 (hope it works as well for elastic beanstalk):

PHP version installed is 5.5 - please change the 5.5 to your installed version if you have a different one ("php -v" gives you the currently installed one):

```
# Download current version of IonCube loader
wget http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz

# Unzip to /usr/local
sudo tar -xzf ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz -C /usr/local

# Add installed module to PHP config
echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so' | sudo tee /etc/php-5.5.d/ioncubeloader.ini

# Restart Apache (if necessary)
sudo service httpd restart
```

If your run "php -v" now, it should show you IonCube installed:

```
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: May 20 2014 22:27:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: This is not an accurate answer, the question is how to install within Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and not within an EC2 instance.should you log into an EC2 instance while it is run, managed, configured or deployed by Amazon Elastic Beanstalk there is a warning explaining that changes will be lost and as the instances grow they will not be identical. The way to do it would be with a .ebextension package

Answer (score 7):

I spent several hours on this and found I had silly mistakes like typos, improper YAML file formatting etc. and have found the following solution.

Within your app deployment folder you need to create an .ebextensions folder, let's say the folder structure is as follows:

- /Web/

  - index.php
  - phpinfo.php
  - .htaccess
  - /.ebextensions/

Within the .ebextensions folder you will need to create a configuration package, for my example I am using Amazon AMI Linux with PHP 5.6 installed through Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

A link for more information can be found here: [Customizing Software on Linux Servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)

Create a file called ioncube.config with the following contents:

```
commands:
  install-ioncube:
    command: |
      if [ ! -f /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini ]; then
          mkdir /tmp/ion && cd /tmp/ion
          wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
          tar xzvf ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
          mv /tmp/ion/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so "/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so"
          touch /etc/php.d/01-ioncube.ini
          echo "zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so" > /tmp/ioncube.ini
          mv /tmp/ioncube.ini /etc/php.d/01-ioncube.ini
      fi
```

**NOTE: When you copy this, you will need to ensure the formatting is spaces and not tabs for it to be a properly formatted YAML file.**

Create another file called zenframework.config with the following contents

```
packages: 
  yum:
    php-ZendFramework: []
```

I found that without these two it did not work as expected, I also had an issue where for some unknown reason my .ebextensions folder was being ignored, if this happens to you simply rename it to something else and back again.

Run the `eb deploy` from the Amazon CLI and then take a look at the PHP configuration, if unsure this can be checked with the following code:

```
<?php

    phpinfo();

<?php
```

This should now be installed. If you need to know more information on the Amazon CLI it can be installed using this guide: [Installing the EB Command Line Interface (CLI)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) and then the guide on working with PHP within Elastic Beanstalk is found here: [Deploying Elastic Beanstalk Applications in PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't the "best" approach, but I've been running this setup for literally years. It's pretty straight forward.

1. Download the ioncube
2. Put the library into a folder called `ioncube` (or whatever you want to call it)
3. Commit the file into your version control
4. Create a file in your project called `.ebextensions/00_ioncube.config`

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/01-ioncube.ini":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      zend_extension = "/var/www/html/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_7.3.so"
```